# CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock takes ages with Amazons S3

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, powershell-3.0

when I upload an encrypted stream to Amazons S3, everything works fine until I try to close the cryptostream (which calls flushing the final block method) . Flushing takes ages and causes lots of of additional network traffic that I can't explain. What's wrong here? Shouldn't just the final bytes get flushed? 
The final result is ok, the file can later be downloaded & decrypted w/o problems.

```
"Encrypting:"
$myAES = [System.Security.Cryptography.aes]::Create()

$FileStreamWriter = (New-Object Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo($S3Client, $BucketName, $key)).OpenWrite()
$FileStreamReader = New-Object System.IO.FileStream(($SourceFile), [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)    
$CryptoStream  = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream($FileStreamWriter, $myAES.CreateEncryptor(), [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Write)

$Data  = New-Object Byte[] 16 #16=AES Blocksize

Do{      
   $NumberOfBytesRead   = $FileStreamReader.Read($Data, 0, $Data.count)
   $CryptoStream.Write($Data, 0, $NumberOfBytesRead) 
}
While ($bytesread -gt 0)

write-host "Closing Streams"
$CryptoStream.Close() #<-Takes ages
$FileStreamReader.Close()
$FileStreamWriter.Close()
```

Comment: If you interrupt the process, does the file integrity still stand? is the file readable? its not clear what type of AES is being used, if its is a CBC type (block chain), it could be that the close requires you to pad the data up to the complete block, otherwise the code will "get stuck"

Comment: Guess it was my mistake. I thought the write method would write to the S3 Stream, but looks like that task is part of the Close() (=FlushFinalBlock) Method

Comment: So you solve the problem?

Comment: yes, even though I'm still confused. With S3 it seems that $Cyrptostram.Close triggers the write process to S3. If I replace my streamwriter with an Azure Blob the upload to Azure starts already with $CryptoStream.Write.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 needs to know content length of the object you are uploading at the time the upload starts. [This](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx2N8LWZYHZHGQI/The-Three-Different-APIs-for-Amazon-span-class-matches-S3-span) blog post briefly mentions that once the stream is closed then the upload to S3 starts. We will get the documentation updated to reflect this.

Comment: Thx for the info. I've read the blog post you mentioned before, but looks like missed that line.